# create and push key value object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array :

```
const data = [{"label": "a", "value": 4}, {"label": "b", "value": 1}, {"label": "c", "value": 2}]
```

I want to create a new array of objects where I have to give key and value in it.

For eg,:

```
const newArr = [{1,4},{2,1},{3,2}]
```

here first item of an object is the key, which has to increase as the number of objects increase, and second item is the `value` from `data`.

Comment: what is the key here?

Comment: @ThakurKarthik keys has to manually added, which will start from 1 and increases by1 as the number of objects increases

Comment: If we have n objects then the last item in the array is like [n, <value-of-nth-object] ?

Comment: What does {1,4} mean? Do you mean [1,4] or {1: 4}? or are you referring to a Set?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{"label": "a", "value": 4}, {"label": "b", "value": 1}, {"label": "c", "value": 2}];
const out = data.map((item, index) => [index + 1, item.value]);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your solution:

```js
const data = [
    {
        label: 'a',
        value: '4'
    },
    {
        label: 'b',
        value: '1'
    },
    {
        label: 'c',
        value: '2'
    },
]

const newArrOfObj = data.reduce((arr, current, index)=> [...arr, {[index+1]:current.value}], []);

console.log(newArrOfObj) //[ { 1: '4' }, { 2: '1' }, { 3: '2' } ]
```

Answer (score -2):

To push an object into an array, call the `push()` method, passing it the object as a parameter. For example, `arr.push({name: 'Tom'})` pushes the object into the array. The `push` method adds one or more elements to the end of the array.

index.js

```html
let arr = [];

const obj = {name: 'Tom'};

arr.push(obj);

console.log(arr); // ️ [{name: 'Tom'}]
```